# Почему не работает useContext?

Tags: reactjs

1-сделал LikedContext,экспортировал в корневой app.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const LikedContext = createContext(null);
```

2-обернул app js в likedContext.Provider,передал value,задал состояние и функцию изменения состояния

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './styles/reset.css';
import './styles/app.css';
import Site_test from "./containers/Site_test";
import { LikedContext } from "./context/LikedContext";

function App() {
 const [isLiked,setLiked] = useState(false)


  return (
   <div className="App">
  
   <LikedContext.Provider value={ isLiked,setLiked}>

    <Site_test/>
  

   </LikedContext.Provider>
   </div>
 );
 }

  export default App;
```

3-импортирую в компонент кпопки LikedContext через хук useContext

```
 import React from "react";
 import { useState } from "react";
 import { useContext } from "react";
 import { LikedContext } from "../context/LikedContext";


   const Knopka_tovara = (props) => {
  const {isLiked,setLiked}=useContext(LikedContext);

  const toggleLiked = () => {
    setLiked(!isLiked)
  }

   console.log(isLiked)

   return (
        <div className="check_like" >
           <input  className={isLiked ? "liked_check l_on" : "liked_check l_off"} type="checkbox" onClick={toggleLiked}/>     
        </div>
    );
   };

    export default Knopka_tovara;
```

После этого шага как я понимаю,isLiked в компоненте должен быть false,а через функцию setLiked можно менять это состояние,и это состояние будет меняться в провайдере,но в консоли пишет,что isLiked = undefined,я что-то упускаю или вообще неправильно понял как работает context?

Comment: А если `value={{isLiked, setLiked}}`?

Comment: @Spatz Даже смешно,в чем оказался подвох,все работает,спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синтаксис `JSX` имеет свои подводные камни. Например, фигурные скобки при задании свойств могут сбить с толку, т.к. первая пара фактически отбрасывается транспайлером и результат оказывается совсем не тем, что вы ожидали.

Зайдите на сайт [babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/repl) и посмотрите во что преобразуется такая строка:

```
<div value={isLiked, setLiked}></div>
```

ответ будет:

```js
React.createElement("div", {
  value: (isLiked, setLiked)
});
```

В данном случае в скобках будет выражение с оператором *запятая* (результат выражения - последнее значение).

Вывод: если хотите передать в свойство копонента *объект*, обязательно ставьте вторую пару фигурных скобок.

```
<LikedContext.Provider value={{isLiked, setLiked}}>
```

Особенно часто такая ситуация возникает при задании встроенного стиля, но в вашем случае это произошло в инициализаторе провайдера.